Azure AD B2C sometimes generates a new one time password after issuing authorization code
We sometimes get complaints from our Azure AD B2C users that the MFA validation is required twice before they are successfully logged in. Unfortunately we have no idea how to reproduce this scenario and therefor it's difficult to come up with a hypothesis on what's going wrong here. Issues does not seem browser or device specific.
When I look in the Azure Portal at the Audit Logs of my Azure AD B2C tenant I see the following for a user that reported he needed to enter MFA twice for the login attempt that started at 09:54:54. The same user logged in at 13:50:51 and then the login worked as expected.
Looking at the first flow I see that Azure AD B2C issued an authorization code to the application at 09:55:19 but strangely enough immediately thereafter yet another one time password is generated. The user entered the same value as used in the first verification, and this times it fails. Therefor we know Azure AD B2C generated a new one time password and sent it to the user.
Is it safe to conclude the cause for the issue is most likely to be found in the application that invokes the sign-in flow? My guess is that it probably has an issue handling the authorization code and triggers a new sign-in attempt. Has anyone seen this behavior before and perhaps any suggestions what could cause this behavior?



Date (UTC)
CorrelationId
Service
Category
Activity
Result
ResultReason




2024/04/23 13:51:14
[correlationId_555]
B2C
Authentication
Exchange token
Success
N/A


2024/04/23 13:51:14
[correlationId_444]
B2C
Authentication
Issue an authorization code to the application
Success
N/A


2024/04/23 13:51:12
[correlationId_444]
B2C
Other
Verify one time password
Success
N/A


2024/04/23 13:50:51
[correlationId_444]
B2C
Other
Generate one time password
Success
N/A


2024/04/23 13:50:50
[correlationId_444]
B2C
Authentication
Validate local account credentials
Success
N/A


2024/04/23 09:55:42
[correlationId_333]
B2C
Authentication
Exchange token
Success
N/A


2024/04/23 09:55:41
[correlationId_222]
B2C
Authentication
Issue an authorization code to the application
Success
N/A


2024/04/23 09:55:41
[correlationId_222]
B2C
Other
Verify one time password
Success
N/A


2024/04/23 09:55:24
[correlationId_222]
B2C
Other
Verify one time password
ClientError
One time password provided for verification is incorrect


2024/04/23 09:55:20
[correlationId_222]
B2C
Other
Generate one time password
Success
N/A


2024/04/23 09:55:19
[correlationId_111]
B2C
Authentication
Issue an authorization code to the application
Success
N/A


2024/04/23 09:55:17
[correlationId_111]
B2C
Other
Verify one time password
Success
N/A


2024/04/23 09:54:55
[correlationId_111]
B2C
Other
Generate one time password
Success
N/A


2024/04/23 09:54:54
[correlationId_111]
B2C
Authentication
Validate local account credentials
Success
N/A




We have identified what is causing the observed audit logs where immediately after issuing an authorization another one time password is generated. In our case the user had bookmarked a URL to our B2C tenant that included state and nonce parameters in the redirect URL. The user navigates to the bookmarked URL, enters credentials followed by the one time password. Azure AD B2C issues an authorization code to the application and then that application detects based on the state and nonce values that a new sign-in should be started because the bookmarked values expired and are no longer valid.
So the observed behavior is actually what you want to see, we were just not aware that this is what happens if the bookmark contains the state and nonce.
